# Allowing RDP connections for secondary user only

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, user-accounts

Is it possible to have a secondary (admin) Win10 user with a password be the only user that allows incoming RDP connections, while the primary account has no password and does NOT allow them?

Owner (Admin)

- No Password
- Does not allow RDP

Secondary Account (Admin)

- Good Password
- Allows RDP

Ultimately I'd like to set this up so I can manage my parent's computers for them remotely when they have an issue, but have it so they don't need a password to access the computer. ....They are part of the "I have nothing to hide" crowd. So security is considered a hinderance to them, and not a help.

Answer (score 0):

To remotely connect a machine and provide assistance to fix or control it, you could consider the built-in functions: **Remote Assistance** or **Quick Assist**
[image]
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/solve-pc-problems-remotely-with-remote-assistance-and-easy-connect-cf384ff4-6269-d86e-bcfe-92d72ed55922

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/solve-pc-problems-over-a-remote-connection-b077e31a-16f4-2529-1a47-21f6a9040bf3